# UITableViewRowAnimation ignored in new section

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I reload a row using

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` is ignored, and i get animation where the updated row slides in from the top. However this problems only exists if there is empty sections above the refreshed row, otherwise it's working fine.

Same problem if is `removeRowsAtIndexPath` and then insert it again before calling `endUpdates`.

I'm populating data using an array not `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: FYI `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]` can be `@[indexPath]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try remove begin Update and EndUpdate.

Comment: Did not make any difference